# Logout code in JSP

Tags: authentication, jsp, session, servlets, logout

I am using basic level authentication and I need best logout code in JSP/Servlet.
 I am using JSP & servlet and MS-Access as backend.

Is it required to create session in JSP?

Answer (score 2):

if you are wanting to "logout" of the application, try:

request.getSession().invalidate();

Answer (score 0):

request.getSession().invalidate();
will not work allowes...
so 1 step after succesfull login time set a session session.setAttribute("loginstatus","true");
on logout set that value "false";

and for after login page include a authentication.jsp
which allowes check the ststus of "loginstatus" session if it is false then it forward control to before login page....I think it will work...

Comment: Huh? Why would it not work? Is the login information stored beyond the scope of the session? That would have caused other (and more serious) problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Servlet 3.0 API, use:

`<a href="${pageContext.request.logout()}">Logout</a>`

That works (tested and proven)!